# OpenJFX support for 32-bit systems

Tags: java, openjfx

I would like to build my JavaFX app for Windows x86 arch. So I've downloaded Adopt OpenJdk 32-bit build and used it to create Java Runtime Image. When I'm trying to run application I get the following error:

```
Loading library api-ms-win-core-console-l1-1-0 from resource failed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\admin01\.openjfx\cache\11.0.1\api-ms-win-core-console-l1-1-0.dll: Can't load AMD 64-bit .dll on a IA 32-bit platform
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\admin01\.openjfx\cache\11.0.1\api-ms-win-core-console-l1-1-0.dll: Can't load AMD 64-bit .dll on a IA 32-bit platform
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load0(Native Method)
```

This error occurs because `openjfx:javafx-graphics` artifact is platform dependent and it includes DLLs compiled for 64-bit arch.

```
$ file api-ms-win-core-console-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-console-l1-1-0.dll: PE32+ executable (DLL) (console) x86-64, for MS Windows
```

There is no 32-bit OpenJFX version in [Maven Central](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/openjfx/javafx-graphics/11.0.1/).

Is it possible to get x86 version somewhere? Or how can I build it by myself?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Liberica OpenJDK 12 is available for 32-bit Windows and includes OpenJFX. As far as I know it's the only publicly available JDK including 32bit openjfx ref. https://bell-sw.com/pages/java-12

As of right now (April 16th 2019):

- *Zulu OpenJDK* not available publicly for 32bit windows plus never got any reply on requests for 32bit
- *Amazon Corretto* available for Java 8 only plus not full Javafx (missing webkit libs)

Comment: Update (September 2019): Zulu now provides public win-32 builds for OpenJDK 8 and 12 including FX https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu-community/?&os=windows&os-details=Windows&architecture=x86-32-bit

Comment: It looks like Zulu has dropped the JavaFX builds for Win32. You currently have to select `Older Zulu versions` to get a 32-bit JRE with JavaFX builtin.

Answer (score 4):

You could try building it yourself.
Documentation including instructions can be found here:
https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Building+OpenJFX

The instructions did not work flawlessly (at least for me).
I had to install the DirectX SDK (from June 2010) and I had to set some more environment variables (WINSDK_DIR and DXSDK_DIR).
Additional information on the build process in general can also be found here:
https://github.com/SkyLandTW/OpenJFX-binary-windows)

For my setup I had to also pass some gradle properties, so my call looked like this:
`gradle clean sdk --no-daemon -PWINDOWS_SDK_VERSION=10.0.17763.0 -PWINDOWS_VS_VSINSTALLDIR="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community"`

However, note that the "Building OpenJFX" page (see link above) stats a "64-bit OS" as windows platform prerequisites, so 32-bit OpenJFX builds are most probably not officially supported right now...