# My JavaFX program runs well on my HP Core i5 laptop but shows just the windows app frame on an old 32-bit desktop

Tags: javafx

It's actually my first time bundling a JavaFX program to an installable file intended for use in a Desktop Computer. I used the following technologies: Scene Builder for the FXML files, some libraries, and launch4j and inno setup compiler for the packaging with a bundled 32-bit jre. Now the program runs fine on my Laptop computer but on installing on an old 32-bit Desktop computer, I discover the following:

- The installation runs smoothly;
- On launching, I get an empty transparent window with just the windows decoration (Minimize, Maximize, and Close buttons).

For clarity, I mean that the app starts up with an empty, transparent body except for the window frame, and the whole UI is gone.
When I hover the cursor on some portion of the (blind) interface that should be a TextField (for example), the cursor changes appropriately to an input symbol, but just that nothing shows!

I need help with this, please!
My guess is that maybe JavaFX uses some graphics or prism rendering technologies not supported by the Desktop Computers in my case (I tried it on 2 Desktops).

Comment: What Java / JavaFX version are you using?

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54179851/openjfx-support-for-32-bit-systems

Comment: @Puce, I just updated not long ago!

Comment: But are you using Java SE 8 / JavaFX 8 or Java SE 11+ / JavaFX 11+?

Comment: @Puce I'm using Java SE 8 / JavaFX 8

Comment: @mipa I checked that SO question out. It suggests that I download one Liberica sdk like that.. I'll let you know if I've done that...